# tweetsharp not deleting selected message eventhough all permissions up

Tags: c#, social-networking, tweetsharp

The delete command does not work tweetsharp, What could be the reason?
I am using this code : service.DeleteTweet(New DeleteTweetOptions  {Id = 4332423432434223})

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked the .Response property of the TwitterService object you're using after you make the delete call? It will give you the http status code returned, and the body content will give you a text or json explanation for the error.

Comment: @Yort ;Response is null ...

Comment: That is really odd. Any API call that makes it to Twitter should set the response property, and if the call fails before reaching Twitter you should get an exception.

Comment: Which TweetSharp library are you using? The original has known problems with some endpoints/entities and long integer id's. Have you tried TweetSharp-Alternative or TweetMoasSharp instead?